# How to move code from Sheet1 of Excel to Module Section of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I had written following piece of code which works only in Sheet1 of my excel now I want to move this piece of code into Module section of my VBA. Please advice.

Code is like this:

```
Private Sub ReviewCheck()

Dim i, val1, val2

For i = 1 To UsedRange.Rows.Count
    val1 = UCase(Cells(i, "A").Value)
    If ((InStr(val1, "ABC")) Or (InStr(val1, "XYZ")) Or (InStr(val1, "123"))) > 0 Then
        If UCase(Cells(i, "B").Value) = "N" Then
            'Cells(i, "C").Value = False
            Cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        ElseIf UCase(Cells(i, "B").Value) = "Y" Then
            'Cells(i, "C").Value = True
            Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

        Else
            'Cells(i, "C").Value = False
            Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
    Else
        Cells(i, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on the left window and choose "Add Module" in the VBE, then copy paste the code? Make sure to delete the Sheet1 code.

Comment: I dunno without more info. Maybe make sure in your code to select the current sheet to make sure it's running on the right sheet?